# Referencing current user in quickblox app

Tags: android, ios, quickblox

This may be a very simple questions but I am curious if there is a best solution. I am wondering if quickblox caches the current user. If you are familiar with Parse I am looking for a `[PFUser CurrentUser]` type method.

If this doesn't exist, what is the best way to reference the current user from any viewController once they have logged into the app. (login is required on startup). I am thinking to just store the Id of that user to use later (NSUserDefaults or something similar).

Also, is quickblocks login Persisted between app launches?

Any ideas and input are welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

there is no **CurrentUser** property,

i propose to use next mechanism:

1) create singleton

**LocalStorageController.h**

```
@interface LocalStorageController : NSObject

+ (instancetype)shared;

@property (nonatomic, strong) QBUUser *qbUser;

@end
```

**LocalStorageController.m**

```
#import "LocalStorageController.h"

@implementation LocalStorageController

@synthesize qbUser = _qbUser;

+ (instancetype)shared
{
    static LocalStorageController *instance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        instance = [[LocalStorageController alloc] init];
    });

    return instance;
}

@end
```

2) Save QB user after login
**LoginViewController.m**

```
@implementation LoginViewController

- (void)login
{
    [QBUsers logInWithUserLogin:@"qbUser1" password:@"qbUser1"  delegate:self];
}

- (void)completedWithResult:(Result *)result{
    if([result isKindOfClass:QBUUserResult.class] && result.success){
        QBUUserResult *res = (QBUUserResult *)result;

        // save user
        [LocalStorageController shared].qbUser = res.user;
    }
}
```

3) Use anywhere your user

**ViewController1.m**

```
 - (void)doSomething{
    QBUUser *currentUser = [LocalStorageController shared].qbUser;
 }
```

**ViewController2.m**

```
 - (void)doSomething{
    QBUUser *currentUser = [LocalStorageController shared].qbUser;
 }
```

Comment: how we retain this user if we terminate app.

Comment: Store it to shared preferences